# Create link without line or word numbers

Tags: livecode

Is there a way to create a link without giving specifications with location?

For example:
I have an xml url that I have loaded into a variable "tLink" which occurs within multiple nodes (using a repeat function). I want to have text such as "Click here to find out more" to be a clickable link which takes the user to the specified url for that node. I can't seem to get textStyle etc to work with variables. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

I think Scott got it almost right but I suggest that you set the linkText to the actual link:

```
set the linkText of word 1 to 2 of field "myLinkField" to "http://livecode.com/
```

Now you can use that in your linkClicked:

```
on linkClicked pLink
   launch url pLink
end linkClicked
```

Answer (score 0):

See if the following gets you close to the behavior you want.

Create a new field -- "myLinkField" -- and put the text "Click here to find out more" in the field. Select the first two words ("Click here") and set the text style of the words to link. Lock the text of the field and set the autoHilite of the field to false.  Now execute this the message box:

```
set the linkText of word 1 to 2 of fld "myLinkField" to "tLink"
```

Now edit the script of the field object to read like this:

```
on linkClicked pLink
   put "http://www.google.com" into tLink
   launch url value(pLink)
end linkClicked
```

Now when clicking the link text of the field, you should see the Google home page launch in your browser.

If you only want to test the value of the clicked text, you can use:

```
put value(pLink)
```

... to place the link text in the message box.

Comment: I can see how this would work, but my situation doesn't work this way. In my case I have a different url that is associated with each node in the xml which I would like to become its own link.

Comment: For instance, why does this not work (with tLink being the link from the data)? if tLink contains "http" then set the textStyle of tLink to link end if